# issue Running Spark Job on Yarn Cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, cloudera

I want to run my spark Job in *Hadoop YARN* cluster mode, and I am using the following command:

```
spark-submit --master yarn-cluster 
             --driver-memory 1g 
             --executor-memory 1g
             --executor-cores 1 
             --class com.dc.analysis.jobs.AggregationJob
               sparkanalitic.jar param1 param2 param3
```

I am getting error below, kindly suggest whats going wrong, is the command correct or not. I am using CDH 5.3.1.

```
Diagnostics: Application application_1424284032717_0066 failed 2 times due 
to AM Container for appattempt_1424284032717_0066_000002 exited with  
exitCode: 15 due to: Exception from container-launch.

Container id: container_1424284032717_0066_02_000001
Exit code: 15
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=15: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:702)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)  

Container exited with a non-zero exit code 15
.Failing this attempt.. Failing the application.
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: root.hdfs
     start time: 1424699723648
     final status: FAILED
     tracking URL: http://myhostname:8088/cluster/app/application_1424284032717_0066
     user: hdfs

2015-02-23 19:26:04 DEBUG Client - stopping client from cache: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client@4085f1ac
2015-02-23 19:26:04 DEBUG Utils - Shutdown hook called
2015-02-23 19:26:05 DEBUG Utils - Shutdown hook called
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste your spark-defults.conf ?

Comment: @user392589 Did you figure a solution for this ?

Comment: I encountered this issue when using stepfunction or lambda to call my glue job, but the job will succeed if I run it from Glue console directly, anyone know why? Here is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66139965/use-stepfunction-to-start-a-glue-job-error-failing-this-attempt-diagnostics-ex

Answer (score 24):

It can mean a lot of things, for us, we get the similar error message because of unsupported Java class version, and we fixed the problem by deleting the referenced Java class in our project.

Use this command to see the detailed error message:

```
yarn logs -applicationId application_1424284032717_0066
```

Comment: For new releases parameter is called `-applicationId`.

Answer (score 4):

You should remove ".setMaster("local")" in the code.

Comment: why `local' - if the user intends to run the job in cluster mode?

Answer (score 2):

The command looks correct.

What I've come across is that the "exit code 15" normally indicates a TableNotFound Exception. That usually means there's an error in the code you're submitting.

You can check this by visiting the tracking URL.

Answer (score 1):

For me exit code issue solved by placing `hive-site.xml` in `spark/conf` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line `"spark.master":"local[*]`" in the spark configuration file if you are running the spark jobs under cluster.

Suppose run on the local pc, include it.

Mani